# RxJS: How to wait for both Observables to emit, except the first time?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have related data. In the most simplest form:

```
export interface A { 
    id: number;
    name: string;
    b_ids: number[];
    b_str?: string;
}

export interface B { 
    id: number;
    name: string;
    a_id?: number;
}
```

The following pipeline maps the names of the B object to the `A.b_str` using `.join()`:

```
withMappedBNames$ = this.bService.allB$.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(this.aWithCreate$),
  map(([bs, as]: [B[], A[]]) =>
    as.map((a: A) => ({
        ...a,
        b_str: bs
          .filter((b: B) => a.b_ids?.includes(b.id))
          .map((b: B) => b.name)
          .join(', '),
      } as A)
    )
  )
);
```

The problem with this is that whenever an instance of A gets created in the code with `aWithCreate$`, the data in `allB` is also refreshed, so the pipeline executes before the data has returned from the API, since `aWithCreate$` triggers it already.

`allB$` is a `B[]` stream containing all `B`'s. `aWithCreate$` is an `A[]` stream containing all `A`'s, including the newly created one

So my question is, how can I make this work with just one emit the first time and let them wait for both to complete the 2nd time and after?

The following is supplementary code for `aService` and `bService`. Whenever a new `A` should be created it is passed to `aCreate.next()`. The backend updates the data, so I call `refreshB()` to refresh the data

**aService.ts**

```
allA$ = this.http
  .get<A[]>(this.aUrl)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

private aCreate = new Subject<A>();
aCreate$ = this.aCreate.pipe(
  throttleTime(1000),
  switchMap((a: A) =>
    this.http.post<A>(this.aUrl, a).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  ),
  tap(() => this.bService.refreshB()),
  shareReplay(1)
);

aWithCreate$ = merge(this.allA$, this.aCreate$)
.pipe(
  scan((acc: A[], value: A | A[]) =>
      value instanceof Array ? [...value] : [...acc, value],
    [] as A[]
  )
);

// This function gets called from the component
createA = (a: A) => this.aCreate.next(a);
```

**bService.ts**

```
allB$ = this.http.get<B[]>(this.bUrl).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError),
  share()
);

// Action
private bAssign = new Subject<boolean>();
bAssign$ = this.bAssign.asObservable().pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.allB$)
);

refreshB = () => this.bAssign.next(true);
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From your title alone, maybe you can use elementAt() https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/elementAt